# How to prove the quotient of confluent hypergeometric functions of adjacent orders is convex?

Tags: hypergeometric-function

Denote $F(;n;x)$ as the confluent hypergeometric function $_0F_1$, i.e. $F(;n;x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^k (n-1)!}{(n+k-1)!k!}$. How to prove $\frac{F(;n+1;x)}{F(;n;x)}$ is a convex function of $x$ when $x>0$ and $n$ is a positive integer?

The sign of the second derivative of $\frac{F(;n+1;x)}{F(;n;x)}$ depends on the following factor $[2\tilde{F}^3(;n+1;x)-3\tilde{F}(;n;x)\tilde{F}(;n+1;x)\tilde{F}(;n+2;x)+\tilde{F}^2(;n;x)\tilde{F}(;n+3;x)]$, where regularized confluent hypergeometric function $\tilde{F}(;n;x)=\frac{F(;n;x)}{(n-1)!}$.

Comment: At least, this is true for $x=0$

Comment: Yes, at $x=0$, it's simple considering https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric0F1Regularized/07/01/01/0004/

Comment: Yes, I know. The problem looks to be difficult.

Comment: But intuitively and visually, this conclusion is not surprising. I'm kinda disappointed it's not simple to prove it. I was even thinking about using Mathematical Induction...

Comment: Or it can be asked as, when $n$ is a positive integer, is $\left[\sum\limits_{p=0}^q\frac{2(p+n+1)[n(4+3p-2q)+p(4+3p-2q)-q+2](2n+2p)!}{(q-p)!(n-p+q)!p!(n+p+1)!(n+p+2)!(2n+p+1)!}\right]$ nonnegative for any given $q$?